# Store images in Database or Cloud Storage such as AWS in 2021?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, image, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I know this question has been asked by a lot of people and I already browsed through some of the existing questions and they don't answer to the technology advancements that we have in 2021.

I would like to gain an insight on the following topic.

I am requested to build a backend app with Spring Boot and a part of it requires me to handle images.

So I am faced with this dilemma.

Will the SQL Servers in 2021 be able to handle chunks of blobs or is it better to use something like AWS or Google Cloud to store the actual image and refer the file name in the database.

Also how will this affect downloads?
If i am retrieving around 100 data items with images at once, does that mean I will have to connect to the bucket for every iteration.

How does the performance affect on this?

I have no idea on the best practice or the best approach for this.
Any help would suffice.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is to build web pages with embedded images, then I recommend:

- Store the images separate from the database.  If one of those Cloud products touts itself as good for images, then use it.
- Store the name of the image in the database.  (Either the full path, or something from which you could construct the path.)
- Build, in the HTML, `<img src=path...>`.

Comment: In what cases would you store the image in the database?

Comment: @LakinduHewawasam - Tiny thumbnails.  Paranoia about consistency across a crash (image without record or vice versa); such can be mitigated.  If your use case is not "web", please elaborate.  I don't understand the "100 at once".

Comment: Oh okay, so I am designing a library system using Spring Boot and Angular, and a feature includes retrieving all the books along with images. So if i was to retrieve 100 books i would be retrieving 100 images too, Would this be efficient in a Cloud Storage or in my own DB?

Comment: Also is there any reason that you don't directly store images on the DB @RickJames

Comment: @LakinduHewawasam - Cloud Storage doubtless has more bandwidth than your server.  (Most home ISPs have much lower bandwidth for upload than download.)  There are debates on whether images should go in a db (versus in the filesystem); the arguments are weak for either direction.  After years of studying the debates, I now lean toward filesystem, as I discussed in my Answer.

Comment: Ohh okay, would it be okay if I use the Database to store lets say 50KB image per row?

Comment: @LakinduHewawasam - 50K should work.  16M (or maybe just 1M) is where things get tricky.  Use `MEDIUMBLOB`.